# Attach brackets to angularjs variable value when binding

Tags: angularjs

Im very new to AngularJS. I've a simple scenario as follows

When no value specified in the input where the ng-modal defined it should show the output as

**`Hi`**

But when some values specified in the input it should show as

**`Hi (Jack)`**

I tried this way

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app>
<div>Hi {{(username)}}</div>
<input type='text' ng-model='username'>
  </div>
```

But it doesnt shows the brackets as I specified in the expression **{{(username)}}**.

So how can I accomplish this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<div>Hi <span ng-if='username'>({{username}})</span></div>
```

Comment: Great solution boss.. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to add quotes around the parentheses, since they are strings you want to add before and after the input. To make sure we display nothing when the input is empty, we check the existence of username first.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app>
<div>Hi {{username ? '(' + username + ')' : ''}}</div>
<input type='text' ng-model='username'>
  </div>
```

Comment: no need to add quote. you can also do this by <div>Hi ( {{username}})</div>

Comment: @KrupeshKotecha As always in programming, there are multiple solutions to the same problem.

Comment: definiatly. but as per this question its not proper solution because it shows empty brackets

Comment: @KrupeshKotecha No, it does not.

Answer (score 0):

here i have modified some code and it working properly

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app>
<div>Hi <span ng-show='username.length > 0'>({{username}})</span></div>
<input type='text' ng-model='username'>
  </div>
```